# MP4 codec support in Chromium

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, mp4, chromium

We have integrated Chromium Embedded Framework into our Windows game to allow us to render web pages from within our application, and everything works fine, except MP4 videos.

I understand Chromium does not include this codec due to licensing issues, but can anyone provide details on how we can add support, even if we have to license a codec for it.

All the information we can find seems to be old, and the functions referred to appear to be deprecated... so we are at a bit of a loss.

All the video serving networks we have spoken to appear to serve MP4s.. so changing encoding does not seem to be an option.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Check this url](https://chromium.woolyss.com/)

Go to menu option Features --> Html5 Audio/Video section. It mentions that Nik's build (66.0.3359.181) has supported Mp4 (and other codecs).

If there is any licensing issues with using H.264/MP4, I am not aware about it, so please check for it before using.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that MP4 is not a codec it's a container format. You need to support all codecs that might be contained in a MP4 file.

In a recent post on a CEF forum someone managed to do it by setting the environmental variable:

```
GYP_DEFINES="proprietary_codecs=1 ffmpeg_branding=Chrome"
```

before running the `automate-git.py` script.

Source: [Build CEF with proprietary codecs support](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515)

Comment: Thanks.. The coder responsible for this has seen some of this information but was unable to find the relevant areas in code.. We'll take another look..

Shame nobody has produced something like Awesomium that is open source to handle this...

Comment: These environment variables are used during the build https://www.chromium.org/developers/gyp-environment-variables

Comment: ffmpeg could cause issues for a commercial product I think.. are there any other solutions? 

We would embed IE but there seems no simple way to do this in a C / C++ DirectX application..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Windows expert, you probably need something that can take advantage of Windows Media Player. Maybe you should post another question.

Comment: We have managed to embed an IE Browser control and set it to emulate IE9.. this gives us a functioning browser within the application... and MP4 video works fine..

Thanks