# How to build Chromium from source with the missing codecs (on Windows)

Tags: windows, html5-video, chromium, video-codecs

My question is related to [MP4 codec support in Chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182394/mp4-codec-support-in-chromium), but that one is specifically about the Chromium Embedded Framework. Also, of its two answers, one appears outdated, and the other does not appear to be about building from source.

I would like to build Chromium the browser from source, but including the licensed codecs that Google Chrome has (preferably all of them). I am willing to look into licensing those codecs myself, though I'm not exactly sure what that would entail.

I am doing this on Windows, so the Fedora-specific answers out there are not useful.

I am making modifications to the Chromium source code, so I do need to build it from source. From what I understand, the Chromium binaries available at [chromium.woolyss.com](https://chromium.woolyss.com/) have the needed codecs, so what I'm looking for is possible. However, that site doesn't seem to have a way to build from source, only to use their binaries.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. It seems like what I'm looking for is possible, and shouldn't be too hard, but I'm struggling to find the needed information.

Comment: You can modify ``args.gn`` and specify this flag in that file: ``ffmpeg_branding=Chrome`` then it will enable MP4 support in your version of Chromium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Finn Voichick,

I am the site admin.

> However, that site doesn't seem to have a way to build from source, only to use their binaries.

No, we (developers and me) share an help to build Chromium with audio/video codecs: https://chromium.woolyss.com/#source-code → Follow the Nik guide! ;)

Regards